# Is there a way to access this (current instance) from within jest spyOn mockImplementation?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

On my test suite I did the following to mock a class method:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    jest
      .spyOn(MyClass.prototype, "loadVars")
      .mockImplementation(async () => {

        const file:string = `MyClass.${
          this.prefix  // <---- how can I address this?
        }.data.mock.json`;
        logger.info(`Mocking all parameters from ${file}`);

        return JSON.parse(
          fs.readFileSync(
            process.cwd() + `/../data/${file}`,
            "utf-8"
          )
        );
      });
  });
```

Is there a way to ref to the current class  instance  from within this mock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions `() => {}` capture the value of `this` from their declaring scope. So to replace a prototype method, you need to use a `function` statement.

Also, Typescript needs a hint here about what `this` is expected to be, so you can set a type for `this`.

I think this should do what you expect:

```
jest
  .spyOn(MyClass.prototype, 'loadVars')
  .mockImplementation(function (this: MyClass) {
    console.log(this.prefix) // works
  })
```

Comment: Yep. I tried to switch to std func declaration because of that. What I didn't try,if it was possible to inject this: MyClass. Thanks Alex!

Comment: One more point, is there some place where this is documented? I thought that I could pass as arguments  of the func callback the current method "loadVars" parameters. How will they fit with "this:MyClass" ?

Comment: Docs: [Declaring `this` in a Function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function). But you can just add args after that. For example: `(this: MyClass, firstArg: number) => void`